# Choose between buttons

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have form
And user must choose between buttons
I made the html code, and made jquery code that makes the option active(selected)
But i don't have idea how to get the choice into php( how to know what user choosed)
My idea is to make an javascript function that creates hidden input with the selected option

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" style="padding:20px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Manual</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Automatic</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Both</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
  $('.btn-group').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('btn-default');
});
</script>
```

Comment: A hidden input could do the trick.  Adding a `name` to the button would also make it visible to the server-side code in the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your form controls in a `<form>` and make sure each form control that holds a value has a `name`. Either use a `<input type='submit'>` or use AJAX to send data to a server. This demo is using a test server. Pick a radio button and click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button, you'll receive the data and header of how the server sees what you sent. The Snippet doesn't function due to SO's security measures, so go to this [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/km3wNni6KSzeyzSCj5WZ/) for a working demo.

**REFERENCE**: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <form id='form1' name="form1">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose Transmission</legend>
      <label>Manual</label>
      <input type='radio' name='rad' value='Manual'>
      <label>Auto</label>
      <input type='radio' name='rad' value='Auto'>
      <label>Both</label>
      <input type='radio' name='rad' value='Both'>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
    <br/>
    <label>Result:
      <!-- Output area. -->
      <output id="output1"></output>
    </label>
    <div>This Snippet will not function in SO due to security contraints. Go here for a working demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/Yv6POGH9Jvbgs1HFoQrX/
    </div>
  </form>


  <script>
    var f1 = document.getElementById('form1');
    var o1 = document.getElementById('output1');
    f1.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // POST to httpbin which returns the POST data as JSON
      req.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', false);
      var formData = new FormData(f1);
      req.send(formData);
      o1.value = req.response;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```